# Looping over jQuery UI Sortable list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two lists. The goal is to drag items from the first list into the second list.
I have stored the correct order in the data attribute.

```
<ul class="connectedSortable ui-sortable" id="sortable1">
<li data-pos="4" class="ui-sortable-handle">item a</li>
<li data-pos="3" class="ui-sortable-handle">item b</li>
<li data-pos="1" class="ui-sortable-handle">item c</li>
<li data-pos="2" class="ui-sortable-handle">item d</li>
<li data-pos="5" class="ui-sortable-handle">item e</li>
<li data-pos="6" class="ui-sortable-handle">item f</li>
</ul>

<ul class="connectedSortable ui-sortable" id="sortable1">
<li data-pos="0" class="ui-sortable-handle">top item</li>
<li data-pos="7" class="ui-sortable-handle">bottom item</li>
</ul>
```

When the second list is changed, I loop over the items to see if they are in the correct order:

```
$("#sortable2").sortable({
    change: function () {
        var solved = false;
        console.log("-----------");
        //:not(.ui-sortable-placeholder)
        $.each($("#sortable2 .ui-sortable-handle"), function (key, val) {
            console.log("item key: " + key + " - data: " + $(val).data('pos'));
        });
    }
});
```

When I drag the first item over, the output will read:

```
item key: 0 - data: 0
item key: 1 - data: undefined
item key: 2 - data: 8
```

But I can see in the source code that there are three items in the list. Subsequent drag&drops will show the correct index, with the first still not showing in the loop.
I tried to exclude the placeholder from the loop, with no luck.

Comment: Both the `ul>` in given markup has the same `id` of `sortable1` and in script you've specified `#sortable2` Obviously it'll not work as well as it's invalid markup. I wonder how you're saying it's working..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

### [Change](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-change)

> This event is triggered **during sorting**, but only when the DOM position has changed.

(*emphasis mine*)

When you hover over the second sortable, the placeholder is insert into it, changing the position of it's sortable items in `DOM` which in turn triggers *change* -

The placeholder does not have the `data` associated, so it prints `undefined`. If you [exclude the placeholder](http://jsfiddle.net/7ta68xyt/9/) from iteration, then it'll print the data of remaining items, which is expected.

---

If you're trying to get the data of new items **after** drop or re-arrangement, you should use the [`update`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update) event instead (*of course exclude the placeholder since that's not out guy :)*

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ta68xyt/10/)